# WP_Query sort by 'meta_value_num' on string

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, wordpress

I need to allow users to be able to sort the results of a wp_query by a few custom field values. These include Distance, Date and Price. Distance and Date are working fine, but Price returns no results at all!

I think my issue is that the custom field I'm sorting by is a text field, and I'm trying to sort by numeric value. However, if I set the field to a numeric field, I can't add decimals to the number, can I?

So, does anyone know a way of getting a wp_query to order by numeric value when the custom field being used is a text field?

Here's my query incase it helps:

```
$args = array(
    // general
    'post__in' => $postIDs,
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => $paged,

    'meta_key' => 'adult',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',

    // category filter
    'tax_query' => $taxQuery,

    // date filter
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'date_%_start-date',
            'value' => $when,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ),
        array (
            'key' => 'date_%_end-date',
            'value' => $when2,
            'compare' => '<=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        )
    )


);  

$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

EDIT

After the below answer, I could edit the SQL Query to use `CAST` to make the meta value an integer. However, I'm not too sure about the syntax, here's what I'm thinking at the moment, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts  
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships 
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id) 
WHERE 1=1  
AND wp_posts.ID IN (66864,44870, ... more numbers ... ,66261,31361) 
AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (2) ) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'event' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
AND (CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'adult' AS UNSIGNED) // CAST attempt here...
AND  (mt1.meta_key LIKE 'date_%_start-date' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS SIGNED) >= '20140619')
AND  (mt2.meta_key LIKE 'date_%_end-date' AND CAST(mt2.meta_value AS SIGNED) <= '20140626') ) 
AND substr(wp_postmeta.meta_key, 1, 6) = substr(mt1.meta_key, 1, 6)  
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 ASC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

EDIT

Attempting to use float and ACF update_field to change the value to an integer, but code doesn't seem to do anything for some reason:

```
function update_adult_field( $value, $post_id, $field  ) {
    $value = (float) $value;
    return $value;
}
add_filter('acf/update_value/name=adult', 'update_adult_field', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 3):

> if I set the field to a numeric field, I can't add decimals to the
>   number, can I?

I think `floatval()` could be of some use to you here. It allows you to get the float value of a string.

```
$my_var = '1.3142';
$float_value_of_my_var = floatval( $my_var );
```

`$float_value_of_my_var` will hold a numeric value.

Alternatively you can cast you variable as a float

```
(float) $my_var;
```

Ref: http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.floatval.php

Comment: Ah, okay. I don't think I can use the PHP float, because I need the logic to run with the Query. But, I've seen MySQL and `CAST` before, which I could edit into the query using WordPress's `add_filter` function. I'm not too sure how to use `CAST` though. I'll update my question with an idea I'm having...

Comment: In your question, you mention if anyone knows a way of getting a `wp_query` to order by numeric value when the custom field being used is a text field. Wouldn't it be better to typecast the custom field value on receiving that variable from the user? The form field can still be a text input but your PHP processing script can perform the type casting. You'll then have your `price` variable which will be of type `float`.

Comment: Do you know if that's possible if I'm using ACF (advancedcustomfields.com) to create the fields?

Comment: Looking at the documentation, I assume `update_value` is the filter you'd use. See [here](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/filters/acfupdate_value/)

Comment: Thanks for that. Gave it a go but didn't seem to have any effect for some reason. Updated my question with the code I tried.

Comment: You seem to have two semi-colons in your filter function on line 2. Try removing one.

Comment: Apologies, this didn't fix the issue though. Just checked in the backend, I get an error: `Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in /home/lukeseag/public_html/codeplayground/woa/wp-content/plugins/acf5/api/api-helpers.php on line 490` and 

`Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in /home/lukeseag/public_html/codeplayground/woa/wp-content/plugins/acf5/api/api-helpers.php on line 496`